# CWOP on current valid H1B Visa

Tags: h1b-visas

Could you please help me with my below scenario:
I got my valid H1B visa stamped on my Passport till 2024 with my current Employer and my previous Employer visa got Expired 2019 .But CBP officer written as CWOP on my valid visa.Can I know what might be a reason for this one and will it be any issues with my Future application of H1B ?

Comment: Under what circumstances did the CBP officer write CWOP on your visa?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I know what might be a reason for this?

It means that the visa is no longer valid for some reason that does not reflect badly on the bearer of the visa (you).  The reason is typically a technical or administrative reason.  For example, your H-1B visa might be cancelled without prejudice if you no longer qualify for the visa because you no longer have qualifying employment or if you applied for a new (replacement) visa.  From the question it seems certainly not to be the second, but otherwise it's not clear what might have been the reason in your case.

> will it be any issues with my future application of H-1B?

CWOP means "cancelled without prejudice," and "without prejudice" means that the cancellation is not to affect any subsequent visa applications (because the cancellation did not result from any violation on your part), so no, there should be no issues with future applications.

(In contrast, "cancelled with prejudice" means that the visa was cancelled because of some violation, for example unauthorized employment, and anyone whose visa was cancelled with prejudice *should* expect the cancellation to have an adverse effect on future applications.)

Comment: Thank you. Could you also please help me if I am eligible for Dropbox my next visa extension if I go for stamping with in my current visa expiration in 1 year ? As able to current Dropbox slots application is asking the question as any CWOP on current visa

Comment: @Kanth I don't know anything about the 
dropbox, sorry.  You should ask at [Expatriates.SE]; someone there probably knows.  But I doubt that you can "extend" a visa that has been cancelled, because the cancelled visa is not valid.